# Set the login screen to a different fixed refresh rate?

Tags: login, login-screen, gdm

I am using Ubuntu 21.04 with a 144 Hz monitor.

I wonder if there is a way to set the login screen to 144 Hz?

This would probably avoid to switching the refresh rate at session startup (screen going black).

I am asking because my monitor is brighter when using a lower (i.e 60 Hz) refresh rate and the screen and mouse cursor feels somewhat sluggish when you are used to a higher refresh rate.

I am using a AMD Radeon RX 6900 XT with drivers from the oibaf repo if that matters in this case.

Thanks!

Comment: The oibaf repo sometimes creates more problems that it solves. With the standard drivers did you have the same "problem"?

Comment: Yes. This problem occurs on a standard installation with standard drivers as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml /var/lib/gdm3/.config/
```

Paste this to your terminal.
More information: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/288643
Notice the folder is **gdm3** and not **gdm**. This worked for me.

Comment: @user1376143 Sorry for my late response. I tried you solution but with no success. The refresh rate is still at 60 Hz in the login screen. It also does not matter if i restart the system or just logout. It always switches between 60 Hz (on login screen) and 144 Hz (on desktop).

Comment: @user1376143 solution worked for me on ubuntu 21.10. Additionally I modified permissions and owner after copying `monitors.xml`: `chown gdm:gdm monitors.xml && chmod 755 monitors.xml` inside `/var/lib/gdm3/.config/` folder. Hope this helps.

Comment: @user1376143 I had to switch to wayland to make it working. If you copy the file when running under X11 this will not work.